# JS popup message when adding item to cart.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cart

I have this line of code:

```
<form name="addtocart" method="post" action="cart.php">
<input type="text" size="3" name="qty" value=""><input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_item"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $record->itemId; ?>"><input type="image" src="../css/images/cart.png" align=absmiddle >
<a href="favorites.php?action=setFavorite&itemnr=<?php echo $record->itemId; ?>"><img src="../css/images/favorite.png" align="absmiddle" alt="Toevoegen aan favorieten" title="Toevoegen aan favorieten" border="0"></a>
</form>
```

Now I want to display a popup when a item is added to cart.php. I have tried a simple onclick event, this works, but then the item is not added to the cart. It just displays the popup.

So I just want something you see on most modern webshops, but I am completely new to JS, so except for onclick I have no more knowledge left on how to get this done. I have google'd for ever, so i thought maybe someone here might give a little tip or example on how to get this done.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Can you provide us your current JS code ?

Comment: onclick="window.open('test.php'); return false"

Comment: <input type="text" size="3" name="qty" value=""><input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_item"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $record->itemId; ?>"><input type="image" src="../css/images/cart.png" onclick="window.open('test.php'); return false" align=absmiddle >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your current JS code :

```
onclick="window.open('test.php'); return false"
```

Just remove **return false** as it prevents the form from being validated. SO

```
onclick="window.open('test.php');"
```

Should open the popup, validate the form, and redirect current page to cart.php.

Comment: you are kidding me ! that simple ? Great! so 'return false' is saying : every action mentiond here is ignored by me and i am just showing you the popup ?

Comment: Yes it means : do not keep on doing the regular thing (e.g. for a link : do not follow the link). Here, it could be useful if you did Ajax-validating and rendered just a message in the window.

Comment: i see that it works now. but! Now it shows me the popup en then cart.php with the content of the shopping cart. I would love it if i just see the popup and stay on the same page, but the item is still added to the cart.

Comment: Well that's another (harder) matter ! The clean way to do this would be doing an Ajax call to a special PHP script, that can return potential errors (such as "out of stock") using Json or plain HTML for example. A dirtier way would be doing an Ajax call directly to current cart.php, but you won't get any errors. For Ajax calls and javascript in general, it's highly recommended to use a library such as jQuery. There are lots of examples around the web, one simple here : http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/form/form1.php

Comment: Okay. Can you just upvote and/or validate my answer as I think it's a valid one? Thanks!

Comment: hi theredled, I found this works great. But what I accualy need is: the customer clickes on add to cart. then the product is added to cart but instead of showing the cart in a new window or in the popup, i just need a popup saying : "YOUR PRODUCT WAS SUCCESFULLY ADDED TO YOUR CART". and in the 'background' without the user seeing it the product gets added to the cart. Like in all modern cms shops.

Comment: Then you have to do what I described some comment ago. Actually it's not a real "popup" you're looking for. A popup is a new window, but no modern CMS does that ; it's always only a message in the same window (what we call a "popin", like a fake popup inside the window)